# How to return output from pyrun_simplefile in c code

Tags: python, c++, c

The code is

```
{
    char name[MAX_JSON_FIELD];
    FILE *fp;
    copy_cJSON(name,objs[0]);
    if ( (fp= fopen(name, "r")) != 0 )
    {
        Py_Initialize();
        PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, name);
        Py_Finalize();
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return(clonestr("return string"));
}
```

How can I get it to return the output of the python file instead of printing it?

Comment: Stop using the highest-level functions.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "Return Output". Python modules don't "return" anything per se, so you probably mean to be executing a specific function in that file, and obtaining its result. You can also play around with the various `PySys_` functions, but I doubt that's what you actually intend for

Answer (score 2):

> I achieved this using a huge workaround. I made both C and Python read and write into a file. I didn't find a better option yet.

I found an actual solution. It consists of 2 files: "main.c" that opens the script-file "script.py" which compares two strings (here: "Hello" and "Mars") and returns the longer one. I still find it strange that it takes ~20 commands to achieve this, maybe there's a better solution out there.

[main.c]

```
    //compile me with "gcc main.c -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7"
    //original source: "http://python.haas.homelinux.net/python_kapitel_26_003.htm"
    //owner is Peter Kaiser and Johannes Ernesti who published the Book "Python" under Galileo Computing
    //Translation from german with many additional (and very unprofessional) comments and slight adaption by Cupacoffee, 17.02.2015.
    //bugs, grammar mistakes and wrong explainations are my contribution

    #include <Python.h>

    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {

    char *result;//This char will receive the return value.

    PyObject *module, *func, *prm, *ret;//These are some helping variables i don't understand.

    Py_Initialize();

    PySys_SetPath(".");//Sets the working path to the current path

    module = PyImport_ImportModule("script");//Import of the script-file, note that the actual script name is "script.py"!

    if (module != 0)//Asks if the script was loaded at all.
    {
        func = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "compare_function");//Opens a function within the python script. Notice that you must use a function within the python script, because otherwise you can't return anything.
        prm = Py_BuildValue("(ss)", "Hello", "Mars");//The "(ss)" means two strings are passed (replace with "i" for integer for instance), the "Hello" and "Mars" are the strings i pass to the script.
        ret = PyObject_CallObject(func, prm);//Returns some python object i have literally no idea about ...

        result = PyString_AsString(ret);// ... but luckily there's a function to cast it back to a c-compatible char*!
        printf("The Script decdided that '%s' is longer!",result);

        Py_DECREF(module);//cleanup?
        Py_DECREF(func);//cleanup?
        Py_DECREF(prm);//cleanup?
        Py_DECREF(ret);//cleanup?
    }

    else//No script found
    {
        printf("Error: No script file named \"script.py\" was found!\n");
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
    }
```

[script.py]

```
    def compare_function(a, b):#this function takes 2 parameters, they are strings
        return (a if min(a) < min(b) else b)#they get compared and returned to the c-program
```

Good luck.

*Grumble, took me over 2 hours to format this text so I could post it.*

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine gave me some code snippets which answer the problem. I didn't want to edit the old post because these two programs are entirely new approaches; One in C and one in C++. Both use the same Python Script.

He also pointed me to the manual page of "system" [Unix: "man system"] and "popen" [Unix: "man popen"]. The second one allows interactive communication, which might be useful later.

[C-File:]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int callScript()
{
    char *cmd = "./script.py hello world";
    return WEXITSTATUS(system(cmd));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("main - argc: %d, arguments:\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("\targv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);

    int ret = callScript();
    printf("exit code of script %d\n", ret);

    return 0;
}
```

[C++-File:]

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int callScript(std::string args)
{
    std::string cmd = "./script.py" + args;
    int ret = system(cmd.c_str());
    return WEXITSTATUS(ret);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "main - argc: " << argc << ", arguments:" << std::endl;
    std::stringstream args;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\targv[" << i << "]: " << argv[i] << std::endl;
        if (i)
            args << " " << argv[i];
    }

    int ret = callScript(args.str());
    std::cout << "exit code of script " << ret << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Python-Script:]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def Hello(person):
    print "Hello " + person

def PrintArgs(argv):
    for arg in argv:
        print arg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Hello("World!")
    PrintArgs(sys.argv[1:])
    sys.exit(2)
```